# Is Windows 10 OEM Home upgrade to Pro possible?

Tags: windows-10, upgrade, license, oem

I am considering purchasing the desktop computer that fits my requirements, except it comes with Windows 10 Home while I need the Pro edition. Is an upgrade of the OEM version after purchase offered by Microsoft, and, if indeed possible, how much does it currently cost, roughly, in the US--is it significantly less expensive than the [new OS license, which is $200](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/d/windows-10-pro/df77x4d43rkt/48DN)?

---

I read the [Microsoft's Windows 10 Upgrade page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12384/windows-10-upgrading-home-to-pro), but I cannot make sense of it. The closest statement that seems to apply is

> If you don't have a digital license for Windows 10 Pro, Windows 10 Pro is available for purchase from the Microsoft Store.

which *possibly* implies that there is no upgrade option whatsoever (and the FAQ makes no distinction between retail and OEM). But this is *possibly* contradicted by my finding posts from people [succeeding through quite complex upgrade paths](https://superuser.com/a/1144126/703457). All in all, I am lost and confused.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely possible.  The entire procedure is relatively easy, and it currently costs $99:  [Upgrade Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/13986-upgrade-windows-10-home-windows-10-pro.html)

Comment: @Run5k, thank you, this step-by-step walkthrough describes it perfectly! Please consider posting this as an answer so I can checkmark it.

Comment: Always glad to help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *Is Windows 10 OEM Home upgrade to Pro possible?*

Yes, absolutely! The fact that it is Windows 10 Home from an OEM source is inconsequential when you want to upgrade to Windows 10 Pro.

> *...if indeed possible, how much does it currently cost, roughly, in the US--is it significantly less expensive than the new OS license, which is $200?*

The current price is about half that much ($99.99), and the entire procedure is relatively easy:

> 1. In your **Windows 10 Home** PC, open Settings, and click/tap on the **Update & security** icon.
> 2. Click/tap on **Activation** on the left side, and click/tap on **Go to Store** on the right side:
>
>    [image: Go to store]
> 3. To purchase Windows 10 Pro, click/tap on the **$99.99** button
>
>    [image: Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro]
> 4. Follow the rest of the onscreen instructions to buy Windows 10 Pro.
> 5. Click/tap on **Start** to begin the upgrade process:
>
>    [image: Click on Start]
> 6. After preparing, Windows will automatically restart and start upgrading to Windows 10 Pro.
>
>    [image: Preparing for upgrade]
> 7. When the entire procedure is done and you log back into Windows, you will be greeted with a screen that says **Edition upgrade completed**:
>
>    [image: Edition upgrade completed]

(Source: [Upgrade Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/13986-upgrade-windows-10-home-windows-10-pro.html))

Comment: Will the upgraded version be an OEM Copy if windows pro or Retail version ?

Comment: @ShrujanShetty: The text in the screenshot under 3. says "Windows 10 Pro will be installed and licensed to **one** PC - **this one**." (emphasis mine). So I figure its an OEM Pro license.

Comment: I had the same question as Shrujan. If anyone has followed these steps, can they open a command prompt and run `slmgr /dli` and share the result? This will show specifically whether you have an OEM or Retail licence applied.