# Buy Windows 10 Pro license keys

Tags: windows, upgrade

We've bought two laptops running Windows 10 Home for our employees. We need to upgrade them to Windows 10 Pro so we can set them up with BitLocker.

How can I easily buy two license keys for these computers?

I'm aware that it's possible to purchase an upgrade on the computers directly using the Microsoft Store (as detailed in the question: [Is Windows 10 OEM Home upgrade to Pro possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/1296041/is-windows-10-oem-home-upgrade-to-pro-possible)), but I'd like to purchase **product keys in bulk**.

Comment: You could try microsoft

Comment: We are always glad to help, but your question is a bit confusing.  You told us that two laptops were purchased and asked how to easily buy two license keys.  Then, you edited your question to emphasize that you want to purchase product keys "in bulk."  That seems to contradict your original post.  However, as Tetsujin already said, if you want to purchase license keys in bulk you will probably need to contact Microsoft.  Purchasing several Windows 10 Pro licenses from a vendor like Newegg will cost noticeably more:  $149 each as opposed to $99 each throught the Microsoft Store.

Comment: Purchase in bulk = Purchase a volume license from a Microsoft authorized reseller. In the future, know that it will cost you less to buy the computers with the correct license included. Machines that are sold with the Home edition aren't usually designed for the requirements of commercial use anyway.

Comment: You can but the license key by this link:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/b/windows?=en_US_Store_UH_software_Win&activetab=tab:shopwindows10   Then you can Click Start > Settings > Update & security > Activation > Change the product key then enter the new product key then click Next to Activate

Answer (score -2):

- Right-click on the Action Center.
- Choose All Settings.
- Pick Update & Security.
- Click Activation.
- Click Go to Store. You are now brought to the Store listing for Windows 10 Pro. Here you can buy the upgrade for a one-time cost of $99.